# load different chat model for different item in recycleView

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, stickyrecycleview

I attach this chat model to activity of "On Item click [chat model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmhAL.png)

when I click on some cardView it opens the same chat model for all card views
how I can make different chat data "messages" to each view in recycleView ?

the Activity of each click listener in recycle view

```
 if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
        // Start sign in/sign up activity
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .build(),
                SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
        );
    } else {
        // User is already signed in. Therefore, display
        // a welcome Toast
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                        .getCurrentUser()
                        .getDisplayName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        // Load chat room contents
        displayChatMessages();
    }


    FloatingActionButton fab =
            (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

            // Read the input field and push a new instance
            // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference()
                    .push()
                    .setValue(new ChatMessage1(input.getText().toString(),
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                    .getCurrentUser()
                                    .getDisplayName())
                    );

            // Clear the input
            input.setText("");
        }
    });
    displayChatMessages();}



private void displayChatMessages() {
    ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage1>(this, ChatMessage1.class,
            R.layout.messagee, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage1 model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

OnClick method

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position=getAdapterPosition();
        PushBotsModel push =  pushBotsModels.get(position);
        Log.i(TAG, "User received notification with Message: " + push);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.ctx, NotificationDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("itemName",push.getMessage());
        intent.putExtra("authorr",push.getauthor());
        this.ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

chat model

```
public class ChatMessage1 {

private String messageText;
private String messageUser;
private long messageTime;

public ChatMessage1(String messageText, String messageUser) {
    this.messageText = messageText;
    this.messageUser = messageUser;

    // Initialize to current time
    messageTime = new Date().getTime();
}

public ChatMessage1(){

}

public String getMessageText() {
    return messageText;
}

public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
    this.messageText = messageText;
}

public String getMessageUser() {
    return messageUser;
}

public void setMessageUser(String messageUser) {
    this.messageUser = messageUser;
}

public long getMessageTime() {
    return messageTime;
}

public void setMessageTime(long messageTime) {
    this.messageTime = messageTime;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may want to specify an adapter and a layout manager if you want to use the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) widget as discussed in [Creating Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Also, as shown in this example,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    ...
}
```

`RecyclerView` widget was first added to the layout, obtained a handle to the object, connected it to a layout manager, and attached an adapter for the data to be displayed. Please check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) for more information.

And, you may want to also check the following references for additional insights:

- [Android RecyclerView with Different Child Layouts](http://www.androidnovice.com/android-recyclerview-with-different-child-layouts/)
- [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)